# check content of a Matrix

Tags: graphics, matrix

I have a matrix  which contain  rotated ellipses and points, how can I check if the element in the position {i,j} is either a point or an ellipse?

the code is a bit longer  but the structure is like:

matrix = table [ if[condition] , Rotate[Circle, parameters[[i,j]]]   ,Point [[i,j]],{j,1,900},{i,1,900}]

then I use Graphics over that matrix but I don't want to show the points, that's why i am asking  how to detect the points

Comment: I don't understand the question.  It would be best to give an example of such a matrix (a small one, as small as possible while still illustrating the problem)

Comment: i updated the first post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`headF1` gets the `Head` of the expression in the specified part of the matrix. `headF2` uses the fact that `Part` `0`  of an expression is its `Head`.

```
ClearAll[headF1,headF2]
headF1= Head[#[[## & @@ #2]]] &;
headF2= #[[## & @@ #2]][[0]] &; 

SeedRandom[1]
mat = RandomChoice[{Ellipse[], Point[]}, {5, 3}]
```

> {{Point[], Point[], Ellipse[]}, 
>      {Point[], Ellipse[], Ellipse[]},
>      {Ellipse[], Point[], Ellipse[]}, 
>      {Point[], Ellipse[], Ellipse[]}, 
>      {Ellipse[], Ellipse[], Ellipse[]}}

```
headF1[mat, {2, 3}]
```

> Ellipse

```
headF2[mat, {2, 3}]
```

> Ellipse

Comment: nvm it works but it gives me Rotate, thanks

Comment: can you explain me  what the #s do in this case?

Comment: @Alucard, you can use `headF1[mat, {2, 3}] /. Rotate -> Ellipse`. Or change the definition `headF1 = Head[#[[## & @@ #2]]]/. Rotate -> Ellipse &`.

Comment: @Alucard, `#1`, `#2` are  [Slots](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html), used as place-holders for un-named arguments. The pure [Function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html)  `headF1` does the same thing as the function with named arguments  `headF[ matrix_, part : {_, _}] := Head[matrix[[Sequence @@ part]]]`.

Comment: ok i thought i had solved this but it seems this problem is out of my league. how can i  force Graphics to act as i wish upon the matrix  ?  only  the points should be transparent or not elaborated at all

Comment: @Alucard, if `mat` is the matrix containing your point and ellipse objects, then youj can try `Graphics@Cases[mat, _Rotate, Infinity]` to draw only the ellipses.

Comment: is it still possiblie to use the command Thick? i was using Graphics[{Thick, matrixy}]. now with this new notation @ i don't know where to write the the options

Comment: @Alucard, try `Graphics[{Thick, Cases[mat, _Rotate, Infinity]}]`?

Comment: oh thank you, it works like a charm